# Search techniques to find desired output with complex interdependencies

Tags: search-algorithms, search-problem, evolutionary-computing

I am trying to generate output consisting of three-tuples (A,B,C), where A,B, and C are three different datatypes representing different values.  I also have a collection of functions $f_i \in F$ which each take in either one, two, or all of A,B, and C as input, and output whether a condition regarding the relevant variables holds or not.  **Many $f_i$ compute things about the relationships between A, B, and C.**  I want to search for the values of (A, B, C) which maximize the number of elements of F which return true.

What search techniques can I use?  It seems that standard techniques wouldn't preserve good interdependencies between A and B values which already exist in the population.

Comment: It depends on the functions f you will encounter.  Do they have any structure?  Can you characterize the class of possible functions f?  Also what is the domain of A,B,C -- are they real numbers, integers, strings, categorical, something else?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "preserve good interdependencies between A and B values which already exist in the population".  What population?  What do you mean by interdependencies between values?  I don't know what it would mean to have an interdependency between 5 and 7.